# Angular Schema Form - arrayIndex as a parameter for button onClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

How can I pass the arrayIndex as a parameter to the function in onClick? Eg:

```
{
  key:"someKey"
  type:"array",
  items:[
    {
      "key":"someKey[].itemNo"
    },
    {
      "type":"button",
      "onClick":"someFunction(someKey[arrayIndex].itemNo)"
    }
  ]
}
```

arrayIndex in "condition" works. But in the function, undefined is what I am getting. I am able to access the entire model or the form's data in someFunction (i.e. i can access someKey), but I need access to the particular item in the array(i.e. someKey[index]).

**UPDATED as requested:**
(Taken from schema form example page)
See the performAction button. I need the email in the button's context to be passed into a function.
Form:

```
[

  {
    "key": "comments",
    "add": "New",
    "style": {
      "add": "btn-success"
    },
    "items": [
      "comments[].name",
      "comments[].email",
      {
        "key": "comments[].spam",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "title": "Yes I want spam.",
        "condition": "model.comments[arrayIndex].email"
      },
      {
        "key": "comments[].comment",
        "type": "textarea"
      },
      {
        "type":"button",
        "onClick":"performAction(comments[arrayIndex].email)",
        "title":"Perform Action"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "submit",
    "style": "btn-info",
    "title": "OK"
  }
]
```

Schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "required": [
    "comments"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "comments": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 2,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "email": {
            "title": "Email",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
            "description": "Email will be used for evil."
          },
          "spam": {
            "title": "Spam",
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
          },
          "comment": {
            "title": "Comment",
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 20,
            "validationMessage": "Don't be greedy!"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "name",
          "comment"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clear the question..post proper `items` array in JSON. so that i can help you. `someKey[].itemNo` what does it mean.

Comment: Check schema forms demo. It is the way to put array elements. I have updated the question with schema forms example

Comment: Thanks..can you please share the code that you tried so far.

Comment: Now I am using the "event" to capture the click event, navigate to the parent element and from the parent element I find the value required and use it. This is an ugly way. The code I tried to make work is same as  what is listed above, except for the actual fields and values.

Answer (score 1):

This was added in [v1.0.0-alpha.1](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.1) with the addition of `arrayIndices`.